# Setting UIButton Enabled and setting an Image for each state is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a viewController which contains a button. I am showing this view controller over another viewController not modal, but via

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyButtonView"]
```

So the result is one viewController floating over the another viewController, where the top viewController only takes up about half the screen.

The bottom view controller at certain times, tells the top viewController to disable and enable its button. When this call happens (and yes it is happening because I am debugging it). The button is not being enabled or disabled.

=== This is in my viewdidload method =====

```
[self.myCirlceButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark_v1_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.myCirlceButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark_v1_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.myCirlceButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark_v1_disabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

=== These are delegate method on the top viewController that get called by the bottom viewcontroller ===

```
-(void)enableConfirmArrow
{
   [self.myCirlceButton setEnabled:YES];
}

-(void)disableConfirmArrow
{
   [self.myCirlceButton setEnabled:NO];
}
```

When I break point on enable and disable methods the self.myCircleButton is NOT nil.

I have no idea why the UI is NOT updating?  The only thing I can think of is the above enable and disable methods sometimes get called back and forth about 10 times in 3 seconds.

/// UPDATE ///

As a test I changed the following and it does remove it. More proof that the disable is being called.

```
-(void)disableConfirmArrow
{
   [self.myCirlceButton setEnabled:NO];
   [self.locationCirlceButton removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Does your code actually _stop_ at some point after you enable or disable the button? I ask because drawing doesn't take place until _all your code_ has ceased to run, so you won't see any change until then. If your code runs for 3 seconds (???) and changes the enabled state back and forth, you won't see anything happen during that time.

Comment: Here's another thought. Does Checkmark_v1_disabled.png really exist? Because if it doesn't, that image is nil, and setting a button's disabled image to nil means "use the normal image when I'm disabled".

Comment: Yes it eventually stops after the last call to enable the button. Yes the disable button exists. All the Checkmark buttons exist.

Comment: I set the disabled image to another random image and the random image shows up, as the old checkmark disabled image showed up. But the issue is when I enable the button the enabled button does NOT show up. If I click the button once I set it to enabled then it makes it enabled.